# ProcessBuilder adds extra quotes to command line

Tags: java, windows, process, processbuilder

I need to build the following command using ProcessBuilder:

```
"C:\Program Files\USBDeview\USBDeview.exe" /enable "My USB Device"
```

I tried with the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
test.add("\"C:\\Program Files\\USBDeview\\USBDeview.exe\"");
test.add("/enable \"My USB Device\"");  

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(test);                       
processBuilder.start().waitFor();
```

However, this passes the following to the system (verified using Sysinternals Process Monitor)

```
"C:\Program Files\USBDeview\USBDeview.exe" "/enable "My USB Device""
```

Note the quote before `/enable` and the two quotes after `Device`. I need to get rid of those extra quotes because they make the invocation fail. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Nice observation! Is there any document which describes that ProcessBuilder quotes every argument with double quotes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I understand, since ProcessBuilder has no idea how parameters are to be passed to the command, you'll need to pass the parameters separately to ProcessBuilder;

```
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
test.add("\"C:\\Program Files\\USBDeview\\USBDeview.exe\"");
test.add("/enable");
test.add("\"My USB Device\"");
```

Comment: Thank you Joachim, you are right. The reason I am getting additional quotes is the space between enable and "my...". Splitting it like you suppose works. As I read a full command from an XML file, parsing now gets a little bit more complicated, but that's another story ;-)

Answer (score 18):

Joachim is correct, but his answer is insufficient when your process expects unified arguments as below:

```
myProcess.exe /myParameter="my value"
```

As seen by stefan, ProcessBuilder will see spaces in your argument and wrap it in quotes, like this:

```
myProcess.exe "/myParameter="my value""
```

Breaking up the parameter values as Joachim recommends will result in a space between `/myparameter=` and `"my value"`, which will not work for this type of parameter:

```
myProcess.exe /myParameter= "my value"
```

According to Sun, in their [infinite wisdom](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6511002), it is not a bug and double quotes [can be escaped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx) to achieve the desired behavior.

So to finally answer stefan's question, this is an alternative that SHOULD work, if the process you are calling does things correctly:

```
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
test.add("\"C:\\Program Files\\USBDeview\\USBDeview.exe\"");
test.add("/enable \\\"My USB Device\\\"");
```

This should give you the command `"C:\Program Files\USBDeview\USBDeview.exe" "/enable \"My USB Device\""`, which may do the trick; YMMV.

Comment: have you ever found an official reference that states ProcessBuilder will "see spaces in your argument and wrap it with quotes"? I can confirm that from my testing, but, it's crazy that no JavaDoc ever states that (or at least none that I could find). Nice answer!

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to split up the arguments yourself - `ProcessBuilder` doesn't do that for you - and second you don't need to put escaped quotes around the argument values.

```
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
test.add("C:\\Program Files\\USBDeview\\USBDeview.exe");
test.add("/enable");
test.add("My USB Device");
```

The quotes are necessary on the command line in order to tell the cmd parser how to break up the words into arguments, but `ProcessBuilder` doesn't need them because it's already been given the arguments pre-split.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get it to work in any of the above ways. I ended up writing the command to a separate script (with "\ " for each space) and writing that into a script file, then calling the script file.

Answer (score 0):

Split the arguments and add it to the command list. The ProcessBuilder will append quotes to the argument if it contains space in it.

```
ArrayList<String> cmd= new ArrayList<String>();
cmd.add("C:\\Program Files\\USBDeview\\USBDeview.exe");
cmd.add("/enable");
cmd.add("My USB Device");
```